# hTried and failed. Newly installed module "requests" cannot be imported

Tags: python, module, python-requests

/tmp $ pip -V
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)

/tmp $ python -V
Python 2.6.6

/tmp $ which pip
/usr/bin/pip

/tmp $ which python
/usr/bin/python

/tmp $ pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in 
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.9.1-py2.6.egg

/tmp $ python -c 'import requests'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: **No module named requests**

---

Only 1 version of python (== 2.6.6)

permissions of files/directories in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
all dirs 755 all files 644

compared all I can see between this server and my working VM, can't find a difference

python ==> help() ==> modules -- does not list requests or urllib3 that I've installed.

Have expressly set PYTHONPATH to the python2.6/site-packages directory.

**Why can't my code that is working my VM not find this module? What am I missing ?**

Comment: I can't even edit question!

Comment: Just for kicks, if you run `/usr/bin/python -c 'import requests'` do you see the same behavior?  Sometimes `which` can lie.

Comment: Arman - This is my first question on this site. I can edit. No clue why you can't.

Comment: Added absolute path to the python interpreter, no difference.